# Many requests in an API vs Many separate requests

Tags: api, google-maps

I am making an application based on Google maps API. This requires requesting for distance between two cities. Now I want distances between many cities.

So should I use "for loop" and make many requests separately or should I send all the cities names in one link.  Which one will work faster? And which one will be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you should avoid sending multiple requests, because each roundtrip to a server takes time.

However when you are grouping many requests this can also take a long time (both to send, and to process on the server), and affect the user experience (long waiting time).

In your case I suspect that the "for loop" will not load to a lot of data, and server side processing will also not be too heavy, so sending a grouped single request should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "DirectionService" sevices ,which is providing by Google i.e "api3".
You can find the distance between the Many cities ,it takes one origin point ,destination point and 8 way points (total 10 places) for one request and it provides a JSON file 
in return ,which contains all the information (distance in KM,value meters,city names and lot more) .Please check this link,  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions . i hope this answer will meet your requirement,otherwise don't mind.